# Adding a point with animation results in weird behavior

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When I try to add a point with animations in High Charts, it results in [this](https://codepen.io/_d3CipH3R_/pen/mdxRWWM) weird behavior:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function () {
                var animate = {duration: 5000};
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function () {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                    y = Math.random();
                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true, animate);
                }, 5000);
            }
        }
    },

    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Random data',
        data: (function () {
            var data = [],
                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                i;

            for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                data.push({
                    x: time + i * 1000,
                    y: Math.random()
                });
            }
            return data;
        }())
    }]
});
```

[This](https://codepen.io/_d3CipH3R_/pen/MWVJpbx) is the behavior I would like to achieve but instead of taking 1 second to render, I would like each point to take 5 seconds to render. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What's wrong with the second example? Changing setInterval from 1000 to 5000 seems to work...

Comment: @testing_22 The problem is with the first example, when adding the animation object to `HighCharts.addPoint`. The problem in the first link only happens after about 10 seconds.

Comment: Try to change the duraction to 1000 or less

Comment: @testing_22 I need the duration to be 5000.

Comment: The issue only happens when I add the `animate` object. If you remove the `animate` object from `series.addPoint` in the first example, it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something happens that makes the animation take a little bit longer to finish its duration. So the chart will be redrawn to a different shape everytime you put extremely close or equal values for the `setInterval` and for the `duration`.

As a workaround, try adding a slightly higher interval of addition to the points enough to become unnoticed the difference. I.e: 100 MS more or `5100`

Comment: That solved it. Would you know how I could approach the problem if I had 2 separate line graphs? https://codepen.io/_d3CipH3R_/pen/BarpxXG

Comment: To fix the above issue, I needed to disable redraw on `addPoint` and instead redraw the chart instance after all points have been updated: https://codepen.io/_d3CipH3R_/pen/rNdjKpy

Comment: Glad to know you could solve it by yourself. Cheers!